# Eclipse, javac ant task reports: nullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ant, nullpointerexception, javac

So I am refactoring a ant script for my job project. At the compilation step, using javac ant task, the compiler crashes with a simple nullPointerException. I simply don't understand what's happening. The ant target is:

```
  <target name="classes"
        depends="conf-files"
        description="Compiles the sources">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
        <compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

The relevant code part:

```
public static CMPEntityProject findProjectById(final Long p_id, final String... p_arrNameAccessor)
{   
    return CMPRequest.findById(p_id, CMPEntityProject.class, p_arrNameAccessor);
}
```

Ultimately, it uses the Entity Manager to find a particular project and use the string parameters to initialize lazy collection (using Hibernate).

The exception occurs while compiling a gwt RPC class.
The stack trace of the exception is long, so I'm posting a part of it:

```
[javac] C:\ECLIPSE\WORKSPACE\PRODUCTIONS\NEXITY_BOTH\CM_ADMIN\CM_PROJECT_COMPOSITING\2014_02_28\CMPProject\build\src\com\cedreo\manager\server\entity\cmp\project\CMPRequestProject.java:569: error: java.lang.NullPointerException
[javac]     public static CMPEntityProject findProjectById(final Long p_id, final String... p_arrNameAccessor)
[javac]                                    ^
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.isCompound(Type.java:333)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:384)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:372)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacTypes.isSubtype(JavacTypes.java:93)
 [javac]    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker$MethodFinder.visitExecutable(DomainChecker.java:99)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker$MethodFinder.visitExecutable(DomainChecker.java:50)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1332)
[javac]     at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:141)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scan(ScannerBase.java:76)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scanAllInheritedMethods(ScannerBase.java:139)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker$MethodFinder.visitType(DomainChecker.java:120)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker$MethodFinder.visitType(DomainChecker.java:50)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:892)
[javac]     at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:141)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scan(ScannerBase.java:76)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker.visitExecutable(DomainChecker.java:181)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker.visitExecutable(DomainChecker.java:44)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1332)
[javac]     at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:141)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scan(ScannerBase.java:76)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scanAllInheritedMethods(ScannerBase.java:139)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker.visitType(DomainChecker.java:276)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker.visitType(DomainChecker.java:44)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:892)
[javac]     at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:141)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scan(ScannerBase.java:76)
[javac]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.State.executeJobs(State.java:248)
```

One of my first thought was it came from the vararg being misinterpreted. I changed the code to use an array instead and it didn't fix the problem. Also, I am aware we are not supposed to use the sun.* packages but it is not a code I can easily change right now.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of CMPRequestProject?

Comment: What part of your question relates to Eclipse?

Comment: Well, I launch the ant build using Eclipse on Windows. Nothing else. I mentionned it to give as much context as possible